# Android unit testing for audio recorder

Tags: android, mockito, android-junit

How can I write unit testing for an audio recorder module ?
As per my current progress, it's only creating the file and no data is written into it since the recorder started & stopped eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robolectric for this unit testing this. Robolectric has a shadow for MediaRecorder. 
For more details on this the following link will be helpful [How to unit test android audio recording app using robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036344/how-to-unit-test-android-audio-recording-app-using-robolectric)

If you have not used Robolectric you can check http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robolectric/article.html

Hope this helps.